# Установка библиотеки BLAS в MVS

Tags: c++, visual-studio

3дравствуйте, пытаюсь установить библиотеку BLAS в MVS, делаю все по инструкции, остановился на одном моменте(скриншот приложил)[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

скачивал [здесь](http://www.netlib.org/blas/)

вот такое выдает
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Может нужно выбрать debug или release версию из выпадающего списка в панеле управления при запуске программы (зеленый треугольник).

Comment: @YuryMelnikov вот такое выдает

Comment: Нажмите на cmakelists правой кнопкой мыши, там найдете все необходимое, и прочитайте о том как использовать cmake в mvs.

Comment: @LLENN я вчера искал, к сожалению не могу разобраться

Comment: Заголовок вопроса не соответствует содержанию. По ходу вы пытаетесь собрать BLAS в VS.

Comment: @VTT если это так, то извиняюсь, мне нужно перемножить матрицы с помощью BLAS , но не знаю как установить BLAS

Comment: В windows отсутствуют какие-либо стандартные подходы по "установке" библиотек. Так что размещать библиотечные файлы можно где угодно. Главное указать их расположение в настройках своего проекта.

Comment: @VTT нужно получается скачать .lib и .dll файлы, скинуть в любую папку, после указать путь  в компановщике

Comment: и заголовочные файлы тоже

Comment: Лучше возьмите библиотеку OpenBLAS(которая раз в 10 быстрее референсного) (у нее есть сборки для MVS, только надо смотреть не последние версии) или вообще, Eigen, в которой ничего собирать не надо - она на шаблонах.